# Video page fullscreen in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 application. It uses Pivot control. In one Pivot I have a Media element. I want to show the Video full-screen when user rotates the phone (From portrait to landscape mode) How to do it? By full-screen I mean only video will be shown in the complete page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `VisualStateManager` to define separate portrait and landscape states where the landscape state only has a `MediaElement` that is full screen. Handle the [`OrientationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientationchanged%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) event in your page, perform any checks you need to in order to verify that the state change should occur, then update the state accordingly.

Comment: Can you give an example link?

Comment: How about this: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2011/03/08/handling-wp7-orientation-changes-via-visual-states.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Following Code Works for me :)

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape || 
            e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
            e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            TitlePanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

            mediaPlayer.Height = Double.NaN;
            mediaPlayer.Width = Double.NaN;

            mediaPlayer.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            mediaPlayer.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            SystemTray.IsVisible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            TitlePanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            mediaPlayer.Height = 300;
            mediaPlayer.Width = Double.NaN;

            mediaPlayer.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            mediaPlayer.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            SystemTray.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```